# How to separately specify a set of nodes for HDFS and others for MapReduce jobs?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

While deploying hadoop, I want some set of nodes to run HDFS server but not to run any MapReduce tasks.

For example, there are two nodes A and B that run HDFS.

I want to exclude the node A from running any map/reduce task.

How can I achieve it? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer my question

1. If you use Yarn for resource management,

go check franklinsijo's answer.

2. If you use standalone mode,

make a list of nodes that you will run MR tasks and specify its path as 'mapred.hosts' at mapred-default file. (https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/mapred-default.html)

Answer (score 4):

If you do not want to run any MapReduce job in a particular node or a set of nodes,

Stopping the `nodemanager` daemon would be the simplest option if they are already running.
Run this command on the nodes where the MR tasks should not be attempted.

```
yarn-daemon.sh stop nodemanager
```

Or exclude the hosts using the property `yarn.resourcemanager.nodes.exclude-path` in `yarn-site.xml`

```
 <property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.nodes.exclude-path</name>
    <value>/path/to/excludes.txt</value>
    <description>Path of the file containing the hosts to exclude. Should be readable by YARN user</description>
 </property>
```

On adding this property, refresh the resourcemanager

```
yarn rmadmin -refreshNodes
```

The nodes specified in the file will be exempted from attempting MapReduce tasks.